# Pooling Horse Racing Odds with a Logit Model

Tags: logit, games

I am using a logit model to pool the odds from two bookies and a betting exchange. I have thousands of data points across many races, horses and race tracks and am trying to predict the probability of a horse winning. So I have created a field called win, where if the horse won the race there is a 1 and otherwise there is a 0. Then I am taking the odds from bookies and the betting exchange as my explanatory variables in my logit model. I modify the odds in a two step process to convert them into probabilities of the horse winning by:

1. Take the inverse of the odds for each odds to get the probability.
2. Normalize the probability by putting the above probability over the sum of the race probabilities. So that the sum of a race probabilities add to 1.

I then use those three probabilities to estimate my logit model. At first I was getting very insignificant parameters and a negative pseudo r-squared and so thought I must have a multicollinearity problem. So I took the two sets of bookie odds and rather than using their normalised probabilities used the difference between their probability and the betting exchange probability, which seemed to make the parameters more significant and made the pseudo r-squared positive (but not that high).

However one problem I am having now is that one of my explanatory variables (the betting exchange probability) is performing better than my model, based on the Mean Squared Error. Even though it is a variable in my model and so theoretically if it were the best my model would just give a 100% weighting to that variable and so my model should be atleast as good as that variable assuming the bookies odds have no extra information to contribute?

Comment: Is your goal to make sense of the predictors in your model or to get the best prediction model possible (i.e. predict correct a greater percentage of the time)?

Comment: Best prediction model possible.

Comment: In that case, I'd argue you shouldn't be looking at significance of parameters at all.  Instead, you should be focusing on which model predicts better as judged by the out-of-sample predicted error (or perhaps Mean squared error).  Multicollinearity will only affect parameter estimates and shouldn't, but you are not concerned with those.  It sounds to me like you are overfitting your model.